# Is there any way to make a picture automatically link to itself?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a website with a gallery set of pictures I'm working on. The client wants the pictures to be enlarged when users click on them. They are ok with them just opening a link to the picture on a white page that is the path of the picture. I.E http://web.com/folder/picture.jpg.

There are a lot of pictures is there anyway using html, css, or php to to make the pictures automatically link to themselves?

Or

Would it be better to figure out how to make the pictures enlarge themselves after you place the mouse over them for a second or two?

Comment: The user experience is something you need to discuss with your client. Either way will work.

Comment: Ok, I'll talk to them. I'm not really sure how to do it via php. I'm still learning in that area. I can do it, just not quickly and I tend to have to look up a lot of stuff. But I'll talk to them. I might go with the CSS method because I think that will look nicer than just linking to a blank page with the picture on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the animation for opening the images, you should look at javascript plugins, the term you are looking for is **lightbox**.

About the 'autoloading' of images, you should take a look at PHP. The fastest why to do that is by loading all the images in a gallery into a separate directory in two sizes (for example /images/thumbs/image_1.jpg and /images/full/image_1.jpg) - use batch resize and save them consistently. That what you do with the PHP is, that you read the directory with this:

```
$imgs_per_div = 4;
$i = 1;
$images_in_dir = glob("images/thumbs/*.jpg");
foreach ($images_in_dir as $thumb_image)
{
    $filename = basename($thumb_image);
    $large_image = 'images/full/' . $filename;
    if ($i == 1 || $i % $imgs_per_div == 0)
       echo '<div>';
    echo "<a href='$large_image'><img src='$thumb_image'/></a>";
    if ($i % $imgs_per_div + 1 == 0 || $i == count($images_in_dir))
       echo '</div>';
    $i++;
}
```

I haven't tested the code but it should work for you by setting the correct path to images. This should draw out all images in the preset directory.

Comment: Thank you. How would I limit the number of images per row? Something like `if ($(don't know what should go here) % 4==0) echo ''` Sorry, if that is poor. I'm newer to php and get some of it, but at the same time I'm not totally fluent in it, but the client wants a 4xX image gallery. They are very set about that. It can be more than 4 down, but they really want it to be 4 across.

Comment: Please test that with different number of images to be sure.

Comment: Will do, thanks for at least putting all of that together for me.

Comment: I've edited the code as you can see. If you change the $imgs_per_div to for example 10, then you should have 10 images in one line. I've left it at four images per line. Try it.

Comment: Ok thank you. It has a little trouble getting going and linking to the correct position. Had to change a little in the final echo. Also the `$thumb_path` needed to be `$thumb_image`. But all in all it works. [See for yourself!](http://new-wav.com/test.php) I just tested it on my wallpaper file on a different server because the brinkster account I was trying to get the file to work on doesn't play will with PHP for some reason, so that's tomorrows issue to solve. None the less than you for the code!

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like your hand coding the html/images?  you should be using php to loop through all the images and build the html that way

edit:  you should look into using the jquery plugin called fancybox for displaying the full size images, its simple and looks professional

Comment: So and please forgive any ignorance I'm still new to php. I want to load all of the pictures from the directory using php and then how would I go about linking them to themselves.

Comment: I found this and eddited it to return how many images I want in a row and I'll add my own directories later. `<?php
$photo_dir = "images";
$files = glob($photo_dir."/*.*");

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
$j = $i+1;
?>
<td height="25" align="center">
<?php
$num = $files[$i];
$img_name = explode(".", basename($num));
echo '<a href="'.$num.'">
<img src="'.$num.'" width="120" height="120" style="border:4px solid #FFF;"></a>'; // .$img_name[0];
?>`

`<?php
if($j % 4 == 0)
echo '';
}
?>` Also if I only want it to return 4 rows per page 4 pics per row how would I the number rows?

Comment: try this, i didnt test it.
<?php $photo_dir = "images"; 
$files = glob($photo_dir."/*.*"); 
$start_num=1;
$in_row=1;
 for ($i=$start_num; $i< 16 || count($files); $i++) { 
  if($in_row==1){
         echo '<tr>';
        }
        
        echo '<td height="25" align="center"><a target="_blank" href="' . $files[$i] . '"> <img src="'.$files[i].'" width="120" height="120" style="border:4px solid #FFF;"></a></td>';
        
  if($in_row==4){
         echo '</tr>';
          $in_row=1;
        }else{
         $in_row++;
        }
  
  } 
?>

Comment: i cant seem to get my code to post right. sorry.  i havent quite figured out the formatting yet

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll test it out later. But I want to at least thank you for typing out the code and getting it to work on your end. I'm really appreciative it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a lightbox. They are quite easy to code, and help to create a great user experience. There are also many ready made scripts that you can use by just modifying a couple lines of your code.

http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: I think I'll try light box. I have time to work on this project so I can play around to some degree. It looks nice and fairly easy to implement and modify.